# 401 from Reddit OAuth

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm following the instructions [here](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/oauth2) while attempting to fetch a refresh token and an access token for a web app.

- I've created an app, with redirect uri `http://scubbo.org/redirect_uri` and clientId `oCEvWuhsQ-hG7`.
- I started a webserver at that address that just echos the request to the terminal.
- I created a user that will be that app's means of interacting with reddit.
- While logged in as that user, I navigated a browser to `https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/authorize?client_id=oCEvWuhsQ-hG7w&response_type=code&state=abc123&redirect_uri=http://scubbo.org/redirect_uri&duration=permanent&scope=identity,edit,flair,history,modconfig,modflair,modlog,modposts,modwiki,mysubreddits,privatemessages,read,report,save,submit,subscribe,vote,wikiedit,wikiread`
- At the ensuing page, I clicked "Allow"
- I noted the `GET /redirect_uri/?state=abc123&code=<response_code>` on my server
- I ran `echo 'oCEvWuhsQ-hG7:<my_app_client_secret>' | base64` to get `<base64auth>`.
- I ran `curl -X POST https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=<response_code>&redirect_uri=http://scubbo.org/redirect_uri' -H 'Authorization: Basic <base64auth>' -H 'User-agent: AUserAgentIMadeUp'`, and got `{"message": "Unauthorized", "error": 401}`

What am I doing wrong? The [documentation](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/oauth2#retrieving-the-access-token) suggests that I need to "Verify that you are properly sending HTTP Basic Authorization headers and that your credentials are correct" - but I'm reasonably certain that base64 encoding is correct, and that I have copy-pasted the client_id and client_secret correctly.

Is some response from the redirect_uri required (above and beyond simply a `200`)?

Comment: I'm actually struggling with this exact same thing now. Anyone ever figure this out?